# Unable to properly calculate [a, b] space in Hough transformation for circle detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

**Code of function performing accumulation in [a, b] space**

- minr: minimum radius.
- maxr: maximum radius.
- Magnitude: Binary output after edge detection using Sobel.
  [image: Binary thinned image]
- Gradient: Direction map. Calculated with 'atan(Ix./Iy)' where Ix is horizontal and Iy is vertical.
  [image]

  ```
  function [A] = accumulation(minr, maxr, magnitude, gradient)
      [rows, cols, ~] = size(magnitude);
      A = zeros(rows, cols, maxr);

      for row = 1:rows
          for col = 1:cols
              for r = minr:maxr
                  a = row - r * cos(gradient(row, col));
                  b = col - r * sin(gradient(row, col));

                  a = round(a);
                  b = round(b);

                  if (a > 0 && a <= rows && b > 0 && b <= cols)
                      A(a, b, r) = A(a, b, r) + (magnitude(row, col)/r);
                  end
              end
          end
      end
  end
  ```

**Output**

Although, I am using 3 dimensional array, following image is in 2D just to show the issue.
[image: ab-space]

**Steps performed before accumulation in [a, b] space**

1. Smoothing using 3x3 Gaussian filter.
2. Edge detection using Sobel operators which returns magnitude and direction map.
3. Thresholding and thinning.

**Source**
I am using [Circle Detection Using Hough Transforms
Documentation](https://www.borovicka.org/files/research/bristol/hough-report.pdf) by Jaroslav Borovicka for guidance.

Comment: IMO it is a little sad to use Hough when you've got such perfect outlining of the circles. (But maybe you don't have a choice.)

Comment: I have to use Hough for a project but I can't seem to get this part right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see in you code is that you set only one point per `r`. You need two. Note that the gradient gives you the orientation of the edge, but you don't know the direction towards the center -- unless you're computing the gradient of an image with solid disks, and you know the contrast with the background (i.e it's always black in white or white on black). Typically one sets a point at distance `r` in direction `theta` and another in direction `theta + pi`.

Another problem you might be having is inaccuracy in the computation of the gradient. If you compute this on a binarized image, the direction of the gradient will be off by a lot. Smithing your grey-value image before computing the gradient might help (or better, use [Gaussian gradients](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22)).

"Smoothing using 3x3 Gaussian filter" is wrong by definition. See the link above.

"Thresholding and thinning" -- try not thresholding. Your code is set up to accumulate using gradient magnitude as weights. Use those, they'll help.

Finally, don't use `atan`, use `atan2` instead.